# Is it possible to use https access to bitbucket rep with envoy in Laravel 5.7 app?

Tags: git, laravel-envoy

Is it possible to use https access to bitbucket rep with envoy in Laravel 5.7 app?
Running envoy command I got error:

```
$ envoy run deploy
deployeruser@138.68.107.4's password:
[deployeruser@138.68.107.4]: Cloning into '20190309072721'...
[deployeruser@138.68.107.4]: remote: Repository client/project_name.git  not found
[deployeruser@138.68.107.4]: fatal: repository 'https://myaccount@bitbucket.org/client/project_name.git /var/www/html/project_name/release/20190309072721/' not found
[✗] This task did not complete successfully on one of your servers.
```

where https://myaccount@bitbucket.org is my account and client/project_name.git is the project I want to clone

I did not find such option at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/envoy

If I run command in console :

```
git clone https://myaccount@bitbucket.org/client/project_name.git
```

on the target server(ubuntu 18 ubder Digital Ocean) it is cloned ok.

**Modified:**
In my envoy file I have structure like:

```
@setup
    $server_login_user= 'deployer_user';
    ...
    # $repo= 'git clone git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/votes.git';
    $repo= 'git clone https://myaccount@bitbucket.org/myaccount/votes.git';

    $branch= '';


@endsetup

@servers(['production' => $server_login_user.'@NNN.NN.NN.NN'])


@task( 'clone', ['on'=>$on] )

    git clone {{ $branch }} "{{ $repo }} {{ $release_number }}"
@endtask
```

But running envoy in console I got error:

```
$ envoy run Deploy
deployer_user@NNN.NN.NN.N's password: 
[deployer_user@NNN.NN.NN.N]: Cloning into 'dest_directory'...
[deployer_user@NNN.NN.NN.N]: fatal: I don't handle protocol 'git clone https'
[✗] This task did not complete successfully on one of your servers.
```

The thing is that I ghave problems with ssh on my server and I would prefer to use http here, if that is possible...

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you specify `https://myaccount@bitbucket.org/client/project_name.git` for the envoy command?

Comment: Please look at Modified